# How can I read and split a reg_multi-sz value in the Windows registry?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I'm trying to read and split a reg_multi_sz entry in the registry in order to list all the instances of SQL Server installed in local and of course, it's not working, nothing is displayed.

Here my code :

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set KEY_NAME=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
set VALUE_NAME=InstalledInstances

set strTemp=

for /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3" %%A IN (`reg query "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" /se #`) do (
  set strTemp=%%A
  :nextVar
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=#" %%B in ("%strTemp%") do (
    set strTemp=%%C
    echo %%B
  )
  if defined %strTemp% goto nextVar
)
```

Do you have any ideas for the error?

Thank you.
Sorry for the bad spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `goto` within a loop and you need `delayed expansion` implemented to `set, change and use` a variable within a loop.